# Call user defined function from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two dropdownlist (StateNames & CityNames) on a webpage.
I want to bind CityNames depends on the selected StateName.
I have written BindCities() function to bind CityNames dropdownlist.
By using Dictionary i am binding both these dropdownlists.

```
private void BindCity() { 
    try { 
        string Action = "BindCity"; 
        int CompanyId = 1;
        int StateId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPresentState.SelectedValue); 
        Dictionary<int, string> dct = AppBll.BindCityNames(Action, CompanyId, StateId);
        ddlPresentCity.DataSource = dct;
        ddlPresentCity.DataValueField = "Key"; 
        ddlPresentCity.DataTextField = "Value"; 
        ddlPresentCity.DataBind(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) { 
        throw; 
    } 
}
```

Now i want to call BindCities() function from JavaScript OnChange event of StateNames dropdownlist.
But it is not working.
So please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnandDhamane Edit the question. Do not add details in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList runtat="server" Id="StateNames" 
    OnChange="StateNames_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList >
```

**CS**

```
public void StateNames_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    BindCities();
}
```

Comment: Hi Claudio,thanks for the reply.But i want to call that function from JavaScript.

Comment: @Anand Dhamane: page methods can't be called direclty. You'll need to implement something more complex. Research about `Web Methods` and how to call them from javascript. Here you have an example http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/